# How to decide calculation vs. storing simple properties with valgrind

Tags: c++, valgrind, lazy-evaluation

I have some C++ code that mostly operate on the stack, working through many small temporary objects.

Now I like to find out if certain values, that are used a low multiple times, should be stored or recomputed for maximum performance.

As some very simplified example, one could define

```
class Point
{
    float x,y;
    Point(float _x, float _y)
    {
        x=_x; y=_y;        
    }
    float get_radius()
    {
        return sqrt(x*x+y*y);
    }
}
```

or

```
class Point
{
    float x,y;
    float radius;
    Point(float _x, float _y)
    {
        x=_x; y=_y;        
        radius=sqrt(x*x+y*y);
    }
}
```

where the second solution will outperform the first one, if `radius` is used for many times.

Is there a reliable way, for example using `valgrind`, especialle the `valgrind --tool=cachegrind` tool, to find out which values my code should store, and which to compute on need?